# MPMusicPlayerController random songs

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mpmusicplayercontroller

i have this code for select and play an ipod songs

```
- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[riproduttore setQueueWithItemCollection: mediaItemCollection];
[riproduttore play];
```

}

How i can load without pikerview a random song?

Ex. rnd 1 to 100, result = 66 and i can play song with index 66 in ipod library

Comment: I do not know how to use MPMediaQuery

Comment: But you do know how to use the documentation. Or Google.

Comment: i use have make this query but not work

`    MPMediaQuery* query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
    [query addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"1" forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonEqualTo]];
    [query setGroupingType:MPMediaGroupingTitle];
    
    [riproduttore setQueueWithQuery: query];
    [riproduttore play];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
MPMediaQuery* query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery]; 
NSArray *songs = [query items];
MPMediaItem *randomTrack = [songs objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform([songs count])];
// ... and then play with MPMediaPlayer, AVPlayer, etc.
```